# ASP MVC SPA Ajax - Public Action Method Not Found on Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

Hello Stack Overflow Community,
(this is my first post).

I have the following Code:

### HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View()
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalculateProblem(List<Location> Locations)
    {
        ///Dummy code
    }
}
```

### _Home.cshtml

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '@Html.Action("CalculateProblem","Home")'
    /* Further Dummy Stuff */
});
</script>
```

During runtime, when _Home.cshtml is loaded, I encounter a System.Web.HttpException saying somethin like the following:

> "The public action method "CalculateProblem" was not found on
>   Controller *.*.HomeController"

The underscores are representing the namespace.

If I remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute, everything works fine. But that's not what I want, because I'm sending data to `IIS`.

Can someone tell me, what I'm missing ?

Best regards, Anton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.Action("CalculateProblem","Home")` would try to find the action named **CalculateProblem** in the **HomeController** class which has **HttpGet** attribute on it while your action has **HttpPost** and another thing is [**`Html.Action()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String)) will call the action and will return the html back to view for rendering.

What you need is [**`Url.Action()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action%28System.String,System.String%29) here which generates the url string using the controller and action name so where you are setting the `url` of ajax call that should be :

```
url: '@Url.Action("CalculateProblem","Home")'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will define Type:POST, it will look for HTTPPOST and your method should work.